# Left aligment when including HTML in Word via include_text

Tags: ms-word

The issue is that when HTML is embedded in MS-Word via the include_text field function, the imported text will ignore any align left directives and keep the text justified.

Trying to set it via the attribute `align` or using css classes with `text-align: left` had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is weird but relatively simple:

The following tag needs to be in the HTML so that Word will ignore it's aligment optimisation:

```
<style>
<!-- 
/* Style Definitions */ 
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal 
{
  text-align:justify;
}
-->
</style>
```